# Building SOAP Wer Service Client using Spring Boot

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, soap, soap-client

I am new to Spring Boot and not familiar with how SOAP web service work.

I am trying to consume a SOAP web service using Spring Boot. I am following the reference given at the official website : https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/

My code is exactly the same as given in the reference. When I try to run the code using `mvn clean install`, it throws following compilation error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project springboot-demo: Compilation fail
ure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] C:\Users\Archit\IdeaProjects\springboot-demo\src\main\java\hello\QuoteClient.java:[9,17] error: package hello.wsdl does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Archit\IdeaProjects\springboot-demo\src\main\java\hello\QuoteClient.java:[10,17] error: package hello.wsdl does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Archit\IdeaProjects\springboot-demo\src\main\java\hello\QuoteClient.java:[16,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class GetQuoteResponse
[ERROR]   location: class QuoteClient
[ERROR] C:\Users\Archit\IdeaProjects\springboot-demo\src\main\java\hello\Application.java:[3,17] error: package hello.wsdl does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Archit\IdeaProjects\springboot-demo\src\main\java\hello\QuoteClient.java:[18,8] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class GetQuote
[ERROR]   location: class QuoteClient
[ERROR] C:\Users\Archit\IdeaProjects\springboot-demo\src\main\java\hello\QuoteClient.java:[18,31] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class GetQuote
[ERROR]   location: class QuoteClient
[ERROR] C:\Users\Archit\IdeaProjects\springboot-demo\src\main\java\hello\QuoteClient.java:[23,8] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class GetQuoteResponse
[ERROR]   location: class QuoteClient
[ERROR] C:\Users\Archit\IdeaProjects\springboot-demo\src\main\java\hello\QuoteClient.java:[23,37] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class GetQuoteResponse
[ERROR]   location: class QuoteClient
[ERROR] C:\Users\Archit\IdeaProjects\springboot-demo\src\main\java\hello\Application.java:[25,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

The code which I am running is at: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-consuming-web-service/tree/master/complete.

Answer (score 0):

The contract driven SOAP web-service development is you need to get the WSDL file and generate the Java domain classes and stub (via jaxb utilities), and you can then develop client to talk to the server.

And the error message you pasted means your client stub classes did not get generated successfully. I could not find any WSDL file copy locally in that github repo, and the access to the WSDL file seems go [404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZZRc.png) as well .

So you probably need to try some other tutorials like [CXF ones](https://www.codenotfound.com/jaxws-cxf-contract-first-hello-world-webservice-tutorial.html). It is very straightforward as well.

Comment: Thanks @chenrui ! I am trying the the above code with wsdl at : http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL(It does not give 404). When I do 'wsimport http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL' This generates the class files for all the classes which define the service method. I know we can use the 'keep' option to generate the source files but I just want class files in my repo. If, I just want to include '.class' files, do you have any idea how I can use the service methods in my client in this scenario?